# Inequality of Expectation of Indicator function

Tags: probability, expected-value

Is the following succession correct? Would it not make more sense if the last inequality was reversed?

> $|E[X I_{X > t}]| = E[X] - E[XI_{X < t}] \geq E[X] - t$?

Here $I_{X>t}$ is the indicator function ($1$ if $X>t$ else $0$) and $E[X] > 0$ is given.

thank you in advance

Comment: The first term has a modulus sign ... which is absent in the second ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is no.

let  $P(X=1)=P(X=2)=P(X=3)=\frac{1}{3}$

$$E(X1_{X>2})=3*P(X=3)=1$$
$$E(X1_{X<2})=1*P(X=1)=\frac{1}{3}$$
$$E(X)=2$$

Maybe following inequalities help you: (I think they are hold)
$$E(X) \leq
E(X 1_{\{ X> t \}} ) + t P(X\leq t) \hspace{.5cm} (1)$$

$$E(X) \geq
t P(X\geq t)+ E(X 1_{\{ X< t \}} ) \hspace{.5cm} (2) $$
It is depend on $t>0$ or not you can use them.

**Proof (1)**:let $A=\{ X>t\}$
It is obvious (see  proof (4))

$$E(X)=E(X 1_{\{ X> t \}} ) +E(X 1_{\{ X \leq t \}} ) $$

and

$$E(X 1_{\{ X \leq t \}} )=\int_{-\infty}^{t} x f_X(x) dx $$
$$\leq 
\int_{-\infty}^{t} t f_X(x) dx=t P(X\leq t)$$

so

$$E(X)=E(X 1_{\{ X> t \}} ) +E(X 1_{\{ X \leq t \}} ) $$
$$\leq
E(X 1_{\{ X> t \}} ) + t P(X\leq t) \hspace{.5cm} (3)$$

In (3) depend on $t\geq 0$ or $t<0$ you can use the fact $P(X\leq t)\in [0,1]$

for example if $t>0$

$$
E(X 1_{\{ X> t \}} ) + t P(X\leq t) \leq E(X 1_{\{ X> t \}} ) + t $$

**Proof (2)**

$$E(X)=E(X 1_{\{ X\geq t \}} ) +E(X 1_{\{ X < t \}} ) $$

$$=\int_t^{-\infty} xf_X(x) dx \, +E(X 1_{\{ X < t \}} ) $$
$$\geq tP(X\geq t) +E(X 1_{\{ X < t \}} ) $$

Proof (4)
simply  for continues variables
$$E(X)=\int_{-\infty}^{t} xf_X(x) dx +\int_{t}^{+\infty} xf_X(x) dx$$ 
$$=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x 1_{x\leq t}f_X(x) dx +\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} 1_{x>t} xf_X(x) dx$$ 
$$=E(X 1_{\{ X \leq t \}} ) +E(X 1_{\{ X> t \}} ) $$

for all type of random variables

$$E(X)=E(X|A) P(A)+E(X|A^{c})P(A^{c})$$

$$=E(X|\{ X>t \} ) P(\{ X>t \} )+E(X|\{ X \leq t\})P(\{ X\leq t\})$$

$$=\frac{E(X 1_{\{ X>t \}} )}{P(\{ X>t \} )} P(\{ X>t \} )
+
\frac{E(X 1_{\{ X\leq t \}} )}{P(\{ X\leq t \} )} P(\{ X\leq t \} )
$$

$$=E(X 1_{\{ X> t \}} ) +E(X 1_{\{ X \leq t \}} )$$
so